# Laravel Resources many different requests for the same Resource instance

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel Resource as a tool to sending API data. However, when I make just a basic controller with CRUD methods - all methods are different, for example

```
public function show(Offer $offer)
{
    return $offer;
}

public function index()
{
    return Offer::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
}
```

So I created OfferResource and for show method it's:

```
return new OfferResource($offer);


class OfferResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'specialities' => $this->specialities()->pluck('speciality_id'),
            'specialities_name' => $this->specialities()->pluck('name')
        ];
    }
}
```

how should I call OfferResource for method index()?
Should I create another Resource "Controller"? or is there a different approach to use the same OfferResource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collection()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) method to use this resource for index -

```
return OfferResource::collection(Offer::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get());
```

And it is best to use a resource for `multiple purpose` if you can use rather than creating `new` one for `each purpose`.

As we all know the concepts of code `re-use`, the very basic foundation of `OOP`, we want to write `ones` but use `multiple` times. That's why we write `Resource` class to use whenever we need to `transform` our data to a array in predefined format. And requirement always `change`, so it would be much better to use `resource` to keep up with changes.

A `resource` class represents a `single` model that needs to be `transformed` into a `JSON` structure.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

Laravel also `provide` a way to use this method to transform a `collection of resources` using `collection()` method.

Comment: could you explain it with more details? I see your approach is correct, but without example I can't get it